# Consuming my own Public API on my website

Tags: oauth-2.0, csrf

I have a website that exposes a public API. I want to secure this public API using OAuth 2. In order to minimize the number of code paths to maintain, I want to refactor my website to use the OAuth 2-secured public API endpoints.

The way I intend to do this is to register an OAuth 2 Client in my server as "my website", and then have that fetch a short-lived token. I see 2 problems with this approach:

1. My client would have to effectively have every scope, since the
   website encompasses every possible action. The API is just a subset
   of this (though I'm hoping to change that). The second issue is
   security and caching of the token. The token would live for an hour.
2. If the user refreshes the page, do I fetch another token? If I store
   it locally in a cookie or localStorage, is there a security
   vulnerable of some sort?

Let's say I register a different OAuth Client for each page of my UI. The would make it so that the token in #2 would have limited scope if stolen, but it gets extremely tedious.

The alternative is to not use the public API on my website, and protection relies on CORS. Malicious attackers cannot access these endpoints because they are only allowed to come from the domain the user is on (and things like nonces).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want towards a model based on a Browser UI calling APIs directly, which is certainly the most attractive architecturally.

This may be the first step to a Single Page App architecture, which tends to provide the simplest and cleanest solution.

See [Open Id Connect for browser apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-04) for latest standards.

- In an SPA the UI is cookieless and it is common to store short lived access tokens in HTML5 session storage, which means the user can refresh the page ok
- It is true that all scopes are retrieved after login, but if you keep scopes simple and authorize in your API based on user rights you can mitigate that

The above token storage is the default behaviour for the certified [OIDC Client Library](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) and widely used.

There is a cross site scripting risk, that malicious content in your browser tab can get a token and call the API - but you should be protecting against this anyway.

Older solutions such as use of auth cookies tend to have their own (and bigger) risks such as cross site request forgery, where any malicious content in any browser tab can send the cookie to your API.

Evaluating whether to use HTML5 storage of tokens is about more than just the technical mechanism - it is about acceptable trade offs around usability and what can be done with the token. My blog post on [UI token storage](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/08/ui-token-management/) drills into this.

If it helps, my blog also has quite a few posts and code samples on SPAs, in case it is of interest.